# PHPUnit Database Testing. Fixtures not set?

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, phpunit, database-testing

*this post was updated on 17 July 1:35PM UTC+8*

I have something like

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/TestCase.php';

class TestTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase {
    public function getConnection() {
        $pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jm_test', 'root', 'jm123');
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, 'jm_test');
    }   

    public function getDataSet() {
        return $this->createXMLDataSet(TEST_DIR . '/Fixtures/test.xml');
    }

    public function testRowCount() {
        $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $this->getConnection()->getRowCount('test'));
    }
}
```

**Fixture (test.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <table name="test">
        <column>id</column>
        <column>key</column>
        <column>value</column>
    </table>
    <row>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>Key 1</value>
        <value>Value 1</value>
    </row>
    ...
</dataset>
```

I always get a row count of 0 why is that?

Comment: but you don't use your stub-db, you still working with real DB and I guess there is just no such table in that DB.

Comment: @OZ_ theres the table there (else I should get errors?). How do I use my stub-db? I'm new to PHPUnit

Comment: well, maybe you need to use `$this->getConnection()` instead of `new PDO` in test-method.

Comment: I tried `$this->getConnection()->getRowCount('test')` and got 0 ...

Comment: @JM at Work: Please double check http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html

Comment: @hakre I actually went there to learn about this. Perhaps you can be more specific as to what I did wrong?

Comment: @hakre, I found my mistake! ... I should have rows in table element

Answer (score 2):

I found my mistake: I should move the `<row>` element inside the `<table>` element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <table name="test">
        <column>id</column>
        <column>key</column>
        <column>value</column>
        <row>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>Key 1</value>
            <value>Value 1</value>
        </row>
        ...
    </table>
</dataset>
```